# How to catch key-pressed event with UIBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

In GWT + UiBinder you can catch clicks like this:

```
@UiHandler("cancelButton")
void onCancelButtonClicked(ClickEvent e) {
    // cancel code goes here;
}
```

Is there an equivalent for key pressed? For example if the user presses the ESC key then we cancel an action.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
@UiHandler("myWidget")
void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent e) {
  // key down code goes here
}
```

The widget will have to implement `HasKeyDownHandlers`.